Symmetric function of exchangable random variables.
This is a problem that came up in my probability class. I don't have the solution and I would appreciate a formal proof. I intuitively know the statement should be true, but I don't know how to write a formal proof with distribution functions.
Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be exchangable random variables, so for any permutation $\pi$ of the numbers $1, \dots n$ the random vector $(X_1, \dots, X_n)$ has the same distribution as
the random vector $(X_{\pi(1)}, \dots, X_{\pi(n)})$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^k$ be
a symmetric Borel measurable function. Then the random vectors
$$
            (X_i, g(X_1, \dots, X_n)),  \quad i = 1, \dots, n
$$
have the same distribution. Furthermore the conditional distributions
$$
            X_i\mid g(X_1, \dots, X_n), \quad i = 1, \dots, n
$$
are the same.

Write out the definition of the (conditional) distrubution function: what does it mean for the random vectors to have the same distribution? Can you prove this by using the symmetry?

Recall the following two facts:

Two random objects $X_i : (\Omega_i, \mathcal{F}_i, \mathbf{P}_i) \to (S, \mathcal{S})$, $i = 1, 2$, have the same distribution if and only if their respective pushforward measures, $(X_1)_*\mathbf{P}_1$ and $(X_2)_*\mathbf{P}_2$ are identical, or equivalently:
$$ \mathbf{P}_1(X_1 \in A) = \mathbf{P}_2(X_2 \in A), \qquad \forall A \in \mathcal{S}. $$

$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^k)$ is generated by the Cartesian product $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$.


Given these observations (and the Sierpiński–Dynkin's π-λ theorem), it suffices to check that the distributions agree on the generating sets:

Claim. For any $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^k)$, the probability
$$ \mathbf{P}(X_i \in A, g(X_1, \ldots, X_n) \in B) $$
does not depend on $i$.

This claim follows almost trivially from the exchangeability of $X_i$'s and the symmetry of $g$.
With the first part established, the rest follows naturally (aside from the technicality of properly defining the conditional distribution). This is because the conditional distribution $X \mid Y = y$ is completely determined by the joint distribution of $(X, Y)$.

Let $\mathbf{Y}$ is a permutation of $\mathbf{X}$ such that $\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}$ where $\mathbf{P}$ is a permutation matrix. Let $j$ be such that $e_j=\mathbf{P}e_i$ where $e_i$ is the $i$th column of identity matrix. Thus, $$\mathbf{Y}\stackrel{d}{=}\mathbf{X}\text{ by exchangeability,}\\
Y_j=e_j^T\mathbf{Y}=e_i^T\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{Y}=e_i^T\mathbf{X}=X_i,\text{ and}\\
g(\mathbf{X})=g(\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{Y})=g(\mathbf{Y})\text{ by symmetry.}$$
Considering the cdfs, for any $x$ and $\mathbf{h}$,
$$\begin{align}
P\left[ X_i\leq x,\ g(\mathbf{X})\leq \mathbf{h} \right]&=
P\left[ e_i^T\mathbf{X}\leq x,\ g(\mathbf{X})\leq \mathbf{h} \right] \\
&=P\left[ e_i^T\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{Y} \leq x,\ g(\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{Y})\leq \mathbf{h} \right] \\
&=P\left[ Y_j \leq x,\ g(\mathbf{Y})\leq \mathbf{h} \right].
\end{align}
$$
As to the conditional distribution, for any $A$ such that $P[g(\mathbf{X})\in A]>0$,
$$\begin{align}
P\left[X_i\leq x \mid g(\mathbf{X})\in A\right] &= 
\frac{P\left[X_i\leq x ,\ g(\mathbf{X})\in A\right]}{P[g(\mathbf{X})\in A]}\\
&=\frac{P\left[X_j\leq x ,\ g(\mathbf{X})\in A\right]}{P[g(\mathbf{X})\in A]}\\
&=P\left[X_j\leq x \mid g(\mathbf{X})\in A\right] .\\
\end{align}
$$

I don't think the permutation of $\boldsymbol{X}$ in the function $g$ is necessary, although I could update the statement to include it.

@VlakecTomaz I'm not getting your point. Can you please explain more? I'm replacing all $\mathbf{X}$ by $\mathbf{P}^T\mathbf{Y}$ to ensure equality. My interpretation of "$g$ is symmetric" is that  any permutation of $\mathbf{X}$ leaves $g(\mathbf{X})$ unchanged.
